# Transfer ethereum programmatically in a web application

Tags: go-ethereum, bsc, linux, command-line

I wish to transfer coins from ethereum/bsc account to users of a web application programmatically. I need:

- Check for bsc/eth valid address
- Sign transactions in order to send bnb/eth and/or tokens to address.

The Server is running linux Centos.
Wich would be good? run go-ethereum on server side or web3.js on client side? Is there another framework or wallet available?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: In order to sign a transaction you need the private key. That will discard running the aplication if the frontend.

Comment: Thank you @Ismael , that's it, I'm trying to clarify concepts before start coding. Can I do all operations in frontend and send to server to sign transaction and return to client transaction signed?, obviusly yes, but what software/framework need to do that?

Comment: Start from here https://ethereum.org/en/developers/. You need a language and library that can sign transactions. The usual languages javascript, python, java, c# and many more have libraries to do so.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.